# Is it correct to create Tuples like this in a single Python program?

Tags: python, object, tuples

Can we create Tuples like this in a program,

```
mytuple = ("Rock", "Kane", "Undertaker")
print(mytuple)

mytuple = (2, 5, 7, 9, 15)
print(mytuple)
```

or, since Tuples cannot be modified, we should create a new Tuple object instead:

```
mytuple1 = ("Rock", "Kane", "Undertaker")
print(mytuple1)

mytuple2 = (2, 5, 7, 9, 15)
print(mytuple2)
```

Both the above programs ran successfully.
Are both correct ways of creating Tuples?

Comment: Sorry! Fixed the typo brackets. Now, please check.

Comment: `('a', 'tuple')`, `{'a', 'set'}` and `['a', 'list']` are not the same.

Comment: In the first case, you create a new tuple and assign it ti the same variable, no problem

Comment: Are you asking if you can redefine a variable? Because you can - Python doesn't care, the variable is just a name. If you assign a new tuple, that works - you could assign a string, a dictionary, whatever, it's just an assignement and Python has no type restrictions on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use curly brackets `{}` you are defining a `set`, not a `tuple`. Anyway, in both of your examples you are not modifying a variable, but you are redefining it. So of course it runs successfully.

An error would be raised if you try to do something like

```py
mytuple = (1,2,3)
mytuple[0]= 5


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to Tuple. Thank you, anyway for giving an answer. I was confused, about which one is the correct way to create a Tuple.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you are allocating the single variable `mytuple` in memory and changing the content inside.

In the second example, you are allocating two variables (`mytuple1` and `mytuple2`).

The difference is that, in the first case, you won't have access to the previous value `("Rock", "Kane", "Undertaker")`, while in the second case both tuples will be available under different variable names.

A rule of thumb would be: if you don't need the previous value, you can reassign the variable (as in the first example) to minimize memory usage.

Comment: Thanks! A question - In the second example, I have created two tuple objects, right? mytuple1 and mytuple2

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: @AmanChawla you might be confused with the concept of immutability, so I suggest [this short article](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Computer_Science/Programming_Languages/Book%3A_Making_Games_with_Python_and_Pygame_(Sweigart)/04%3A_Memory_Puzzle/4.12%3A_Tuples_vs._Lists%2C_Immutable_vs._Mutable) explaining what it really means.